# Serve both text and image data when rendering a template?

Tags: node.js, express, content-type

Trying to send both text and image data as local variables to a server-side rendered page using templates.
I know I have to set the Content-Type as 'image/png'.
How can I set the Content-Type for one variable when all the other variables are text?
Thank you so much!

```
res.render('profile.html', { locals: {
  tasks: tasks,
  msgExists: '',
  name: req.user.name,
  email: req.user.email,
  photo: req.user.photo //how to set Content-Type for this variable?
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the template is rendered on server side, and then sent to client. this means the content type of the response is "text/html", not "image/png".

your variables do not have "Content-Type", as they are not HTML responses. if you want to embed an image in an html, and you know its raw data, it usually looks like this:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
```

now if you have the image data (like whatever after base64 part) somehow stored in a JS variable, and want to pass it to your template renderer to embed that image in the resulting html, it would look like this:

```js
// node js code:
imgData = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
res.render('my.template.html', {
  imgData, 
  // whatever else ...
});
```

```html
  <!-- template code: -->

  <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{imgData}}"/>

  <!-- whatever else -->
```

of course this can change a bit based on the exact format you are storing the image data.

Comment: **NOTE**: this is a strict answer to the question you asked. however, just in case there is a confusion, I need to ask: are you sure `req.user.photo` is image data and not just an image URL? are you for example storing raw image data in some DB or something?

Comment: Eugene, Thanks for the answer. I will digest it tomorrow. But quick response, yes, under the photo field in the User model, the value reads <binary>. Thank you again.